# Setting an Image to my Image control

Tags: silverlight, image, xaml

```
private void SetShipmentStatus(bool status)
{
    if (status)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "Su envio fue entregado!";
        imgStatus.Source = ???
    }
}
```

How can I give my XAML Image control a source programatically? I have the image in this location as Resource:

[image]